# Replace Max 7456 EEPROM w/ ASCII Table

Tags: arduino-uno, hyperterminal, breakout

I have a a Sparkfun Max 7456 breakout board that I am trying to rewrite the character table to an ASCII format.  I have been following the Arduino + MAX7456 OSD thread but cannot seem to load the .mcm file to the breakout board.  I have tried hyper terminal and tera term.  Tera term allows me to "transfer" the mcm file but I do not get any type of confirmation in the terminal window.  When I try simple sample code like "Hello World.ino" I get no response and the default character set is still displayed.  Hyper terminal tells me there is a COM port conflict with the Arduino IDE.  I know the steps are available in the above mentioned thread but the picture/ code resources have mostly been removed.  I don't know if I'm missing something in the code or if I am not using the terminal program correctly.  I have the following connections between the breakout board and the Uno and have been trying Arduino code provided at the start of the thread;

```
Breakout/ Uno;

CS-->D10
SDIN--> D11
SCK--> D12
SDOUT--> D13
+5V
GND

 I have tried using wires that are <5cm and >=10cm and I am using NTSC.  Can anybody determine what I am doing wrong or point me in the right direction please.  Thanks in advance,
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue.  Using Google translate I was able to get code from;

http://f5mna.free.fr/Arduiexpert.htm

Previously, I was only making the connections listed in the code when the full list is;

```
D13--> SCLK
D12--> SDOUT
D11--> SDIN
D10--> CS
```

+5VDC must be applied to the +5V pin on the board as well as a 1k resistor in series with LOS and a 10k with RESET.

As for using tera term.  First shutdown the Arduino IDE and open the connection in the terminal program.  The code provided in the above link will indicate it is ready for file transfer and will prompt you with a transfer complete message.

All in all, simple solutions but I was a newcomer to a very old thread.  Hope this helps anyone else having the same issues in the future.